# Асинхронные запросы на сервер с ID

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, асинхронность

Стоит такая задача.
Есть сервер, доступ к нему осуществляется по IP адресу через HTTP, он запрашивает логин-пароль.

Клиент создает запрос, отправляет JSON объект с этим запросом, сервер обрабатывает этот JSON, делает нужную операцию, возвращает ответ. 
Запросов может быть много, и каждому из них присваивается ID. Это нужно для того, чтобы асинхронно закидывать сервер запросами, а потом определять, ответ на какой именно запрос прислал сервер.
Для этого думаю использовать Map. Но не уверен, что это верный подход.
Плюс, не получается создать подключение к серверу - сколько ни копаю, не понимаю, как его сделать. Уже пересмотрел кучу видео, перелопатил форумы...

блок с подключением к серверу тут я не написал, потому что уже несколько вариантов испробовал, и все оно не работает

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Random;


public class CertexCloudTotalTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userName = "*******";
        String userPassword = "********";
        String serverAddress = "********";

        Map<Integer, req> requestsWithIDs = new HashMap<Integer, req>();

        try {
            URL conn = new URL(serverAddress);
            URLConnection connection = conn.openConnection();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static int generateID () {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: Во-первых, в вашем примере кода запросы синхронные. Во-вторых, вы используете HTTP, а значит одно соединение - один запрос - один ответ, идентификация не нужна.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что пока они синхронные тут. Это просто пока не реализовано - мне бы сначала просто подключиться к серверу.)  А что касается HTTP - не совсем понял. Трудность в том, что если запросы асинхронно посылаются, то кто даст мне гарантию, что полученный ответ был дан именно на тот запрос, что был послан? То есть один запрос - один ответ, это ясно. Но ведь ответ может прийти сформированный для другого запроса.

Comment: Видать, вы вообще не представляете как асинхронщина в принципе работает. Вместо того, чтобы гадать на отвлечённые темы, выберите конкретный механизм асинхронного сетевого взаимодействия и разберитесь на конкретных примерах.

Comment: в том и дело, что ничего конкретного найти не удалось, иначе бы разобрался) Гугл, stackoverflow, и другие сайты и форумы завалены, в основном, мусором, в котором найти хоть что-то стоящее нереально) Я про нормальные объяснения, а не про примеры кода. Примеров то полно, но все они бессмысленны без детального объяснения, которого нет нигде. Что ж, спасибо за уделенное время.